# Android memory keeps on growing after AsyncTask completes

Tags: android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, android-asynctask, garbage-collection

I have an inner `AsyncTask` Class which downloads a large `ArrayList` from the DB on the `doInBackground()` method and initialize a arrayAdapter on the `onPostExecute()` to show he data on a `ListView`. The `AsyncTask` is called from the `onCreateView()` function of a `DialogFragment`.

Everything is working fine as expected and when I monitor the memory allocations, the number of allocated memory is constant before I open the fragment.

But when the fragment is opened and and after everything is displayed by the `AsyncTask` the allocated memory keeps on growing and GC_FOR_ALLOC is called and stays growing.

This keeps on happening even if I close the fragment. The rate of memory allocation keeps doubling when I open the fragment again and again.

This does not happen if I remove the `AsyncTask` and do all the things inside the `onCreateView()` function of the fragment. However the UI tends to be not responsive if I do that but the memory issue won't be there.

Please help me. Shown below is `AsyncTask` my code

```
public class GenerateItemsForBasketAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer,  List<beTableSaleItem>> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected  List<beTableSaleItem> doInBackground(String...params) {

        if(bePOS.getInstance().getBasket().getOrderNo()!="-99")
        {
            return ORMLiteDBManager.getInstance().getAllTableSalesItemsForTableSale(params[0]);
        }
        else
        {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<beTableSaleItem> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        basketItems = result;

        if (basketItems.size() > 0) {
            basketAdaptor = new BasketListAdaptor();
            basketListView.setAdapter(basketAdaptor);
            btnMakeOrder.setEnabled(true);
            btnAddToBasket.setEnabled(true);
        }

        basketListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loadingProgress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnBack.setEnabled(true);
        btnCom.setEnabled(true);

        beTableSale tableSale = ORMLiteDBManager.getInstance().getTableSaleForOrderNo(bePOS.getInstance().getBasket().getOrderNo());
        if(!(tableSale!=null && tableSale.getWaiterOrderStatus().equals(Constant.STATUS_CHEQUE)))
        {
            btnMoveOrder.setEnabled(true);
        }

    }
}
```

The above AsyncTask is an inner class in my Dialog Fragment and called as shown below from the onCreateView()

```
new GenerateItemsForBasketAsync().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, orderNo);
```

Comment: Please show the code using the AsyncTask

Comment: I added the AsyncTask using code

Comment: One thing I noticed: If your AsyncTask doesn't use publishProgress, your progress type should be `Void` to optimize performance. Try to check if your AsyncTask gets created multiple times. Also it might be a better idea to start this process in onCreate instead of onCreateView, because this gets called earlier.

Comment: No the AsyncTask is only called once the fragment is open and does not get create multiple times. I changed it to onCreate() and made the progress to Void but still the same

Comment: Try to use execute instead of executeOnExecutor

Comment: I tried both the ways but still the same

Comment: We need more information on what exactly causes the leak. Try to narrow down the problem with methods described here http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html